# What does running_total mean in javascript d3?

Tags: javascript

I saw some JS codes like this

```
dsv(',','data.csv').then(data => {
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.running_total = +d.running_total
  });
  render(data);
});
```

What does running_total mean?

Comment: That's just a property of the object defined by the user...

Comment: see your data.csv file, it should be a prop in that.